# how to write a query by using some filter patterns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

what I want is to apply some filter patterns to search the data. For example. There is a large physical table in the database regarding medicines, I want to allow search even if user write lasix, lasixx, lasixxx, lasax, lasi, lisax. Data should be retrieved for the medicine lasix. How can I write these filter patterns in SQL query? And this query should be compilent with old SQL server versions like 2008 as well. I want to do it in SQL Server side instead of c# logic. Help and assistance is really appreciated.

```
Select Name from medicines where Name like '%lasixxx%'
```

Sample data is

```
Id Name
 1 lasix
 2 panadol
 3 Augmentin 
 4 cefixime
 5 xyrem
```

Hard coded condions can't be applied because there is a lot of data in the table and I can't place the multiple conditions only for a single medicine.

Performance should not be compromised

Comment: A set of sample data would greatly help us assist you here.

Comment: OK plz check above.

Comment: Levenshtein distance maybe? There is no built in function for it, but people have built such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case you might find the [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) will work for you.

Another option might be [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

But in general, SQL is not always the best way to achieve this kind of search.  One of the no-SQLs like elastic search might be better though organisationally it might be more difficult to get going than just sticking with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the filter with `or` expressions:

```
Select Name from medicines
where Name like '%lasi%'
or Name like '%lasax%'
or Name like '%lisax%'
```

Please note that lasix, lasixx and lasixxx are already included in %lasi%.

Comment: Thank you Rafael I but there are millions of medicines. How can I place multiple conditions for 3 x millions of medicines?  It's impossible and not an efficient wY

Comment: maybe you can create a related table containing the possible patterns, then with an inner join you can perform a very fast query